# Kuberenetes - SSL termination at ingress level

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb

How can I access the httpd pods when using ingress? The httpd pod is plain httpd. So I want to do ssl termination at ingress level. I've created a hosted zone in Route 53.

Right now I can only access the httpd pod using `<loadbalancer_ip>:<port_8080>`. But after login it redirects to https which doesn't work. I believe I need to do ssl termination at ingress level

`ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-04T18:53:16Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: manageiq
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

`service.yaml:`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-08-04T20:38:54Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: manageiq
  name: httpd
  namespace: default
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 100.64.xxx.xx
  clusterIPs:
  - 100.64.xxx.xx
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31616
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    name: httpd
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress: af0b82c4-999387977.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Your service should not be of type loadbalancer if you use ingress. You also need to deploy an ingress controller. Usually those do tls termination by default. However, I think the redirection comes from a apache misconfiguration, since you already reached it on http. So any redirect should come from httpd itself.

Comment: What should I do to prevent  `http://example.com:8080 -> https://example.com` ?